# Groovy Rest-Assured missing method exception for ArrayList

Tags: groovy, rest-assured

I'm using IntelliJ here and I'm getting a missing method exception that I can't figure out in this Groovy implementation of RestAssured.  The suspect method is this:

```
when().get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
            .then().body("id", equalTo(1))
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.toSorted() is applicable for argument types: (io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$_applyPathParamsAndSendRequest_closure32) values: [io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$_applyPathParamsAndSendRequest_closure32@4d9e68d0]
Possible solutions: toSet(), toString(), toString(), toString(), toString(), sort()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1715)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1206)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:806)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1731)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1206)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:806)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:168)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1206)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:806)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at Main.main(Main.groovy:11)
```

I have the following imports currently:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*
import static io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
```

I'm just aiming at a generic api out on the web for a demo.  I've tried various things and it always seems to come down to the get() call itself.  It also happens on the post() call I make.  With the get(), if I remove everything except the get() itself, so no then() or anything after, I still get the exception.

I feel like this is some issue with the java libraries not being picked up, but heck if I understand what that might be.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue and found that this is because of missing `Groovy` dependency, add it in your `pom` and your problem should be solved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.11

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I'v added the below dependency to fix the issue.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
```